# SQL get an id from a column where ids separated by commas

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have a column named `id` with a bunch of ids separated by commas like this:

`asdaxxdfd2,wwfsfdssdfsd6,sdfdsfdsed2,23445rr55`

I need to match an id from the column to an existing `$user_id`

Trying this didn't do it:

`"SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id LIKE '%" . $user_id . "%'";`

Not sure what else I can do.

Thank you.

Comment: time to normalise your data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible without normalization?

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: possible or not, no one should store data like this and normalisation is the bet solution here

Comment: @stickybit maria database

Comment: Please add it to the tags then.

Comment: @smith I am afraid it would not be possible since I have so much data to deal with.

Comment: Also consider reading about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). The snippet suggests, that your program might be vulnerable.

Comment: @VitaliKloster - "so much data to deal with" -- How much?

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE concat(',', id, ',') LIKE '%," . $user_id . ",%';"
```

should do it.

But I also strongly recommend to normalize the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit ambiguous, I don't know if this solution is what you intends:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(id, '[^,]+', 1, 1) COLUMN_1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(id, '[^,]+', 1, 2) COLUMN_2,
FROM my_table;

or just

SELECT id
FROM my_table
WHERE id LIKE '%wwfsfdssdfsd6%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(id," . $user_id . ") UserID FROM my_table;
```

This will return the matching user id but again using a database with values stored in a single row is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id REGEXP "[[:<:]]$user_id[[:>:]]";
```

Those match "word boundaries", thereby handling beginning and end of string.

But, without normalizing there is no way to make a query that runs faster than a full table scan.